# Magento 2: How to get a customer by Telephone attribute?

Tags: magento2, attributes, collection

I'd like to filter my collection using something like:

```
$collection->setField('telephone')
  ->setConditionType('eq')
  ->setValue('(555) 229-3326')
```

But the **telephone** attribute is an attribute on **Default Billing Address**, how can I do that?

Comment: You only need customer where telephone = "value" ? or Want customer from orders

Comment: I need to get the customer where telephone="value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add default address  telephone to collection by add **joinAttribute**() to collection.

```
$collection
 ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('billing_telephone','(555) 229-3326');
```

Comment: What a bad mistake.i did.Thanks to Rafeal

Answer (score 0):

You can get customer using Join on customer collection.

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'), 'e.entity_id = billing.customer_id',array('telephone' =>'telephone') )->where("billing.address_type =  'billing'  AND billing.telephone = '(555) 229-3326'");
```